# Node.js error: read ECONNRESET using ssh2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to use ssh2 from npm to setup an ssh connection and remotely login to a machine. The code works fine for Windows to Linux/MacOS connections but fails for Windows to Windows connection(the error screenshot has been attached). I did find something related to agent and agentForward parameters that might be causing the problem but couldn't find a solution to it. Node Version: 8.11.2
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
The code is as follows:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function() 
    {
        console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.exec('systeminfo', function(err, stream) 
        {//system_profiler SPHardwareDataType, systeminfo
            if (err) console.log(err);
            stream.on('close', function(code, signal) 
            {
            console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
            conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) 
            {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) 
            {
                console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
        });
    }).connect({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 22,
    username: 'inspiron',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('C:/Users/inspiron/Downloads/private_key.ppk')
    });
    res.send(str);
});
```

This is the Error Message:

[image]

Comment: Try providing code in the post itself rather than external link. Link url may expire in future and it won't useful to someone who will be facing same issue.

Comment: I am sorry... this is the first question I have posted on stack overflow. Still getting used to using it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you get a solution? @sarthak97

Comment: Yes...I had to change my approach though. @codename_47

Comment: @sarthak97 what was your solution? Please add it then mark as the answer.

Comment: @sarthak97, i am also facing the same problem. I am also executing a simple command like "ls"  from almost same code. it is giving me result but throwing the same error. please share what solution you applied to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give up on the above approach i.e. using ssh2 since I couldn't find a solution for the error being faced.

What I did instead was to run powershell scripts:

- The first script simply ran the [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) cmdlet to check whether the machine at a given IP address was reachable or not.
- Next, a powershell script was run on the host machine using [child-process](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/) in Node.js to get the required parameters(such as Hostname, RAM, OS etc.) from the remote machine which should be a Windows machine.
- If the second script was not run on a windows machine, it would fail with an error and then a third powershell script would run which has been made specifically for Linux based machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar problem.

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:618:25)
```

Though I added some delay and it somehow works.

```
stream.on('close', function(code, signal){
  console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
  //extra lines of code here..
  conn.end();
}
```

Add some delay or try-catch statement; also with  "stream.on('data', function(data) {...

```
stream.on('close', function(code, signal){
  console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
  //var newvar = oldvar;

  setTimeout(function() {
    conn.end();
    //use the newvar here..
    //extra lines of code..
  },100);
}
```